# media print css issue

Tags: css, print-css

I need details about media, print which we can use as best practice. My HTML page is a dynamic one. Data will be vary frequently, I wrote media print css, but in all cases it is not working as expected. One or other data is missing in print.
Please help me out of this

Comment: @media print is not working properly in chrome.

Comment: Please provide code snippets or other details on what you are trying to achieve so that others can help you find a solution.